# Array declarators: confusion with "it is unspecified whether or not the size expression is evaluated"

Tags: arrays, c, language-lawyer, declaration

C11, 6.7.6.2 Array declarators, Semantics, 5:

> Where a size expression is part of the operand of a `sizeof` operator and changing the value of the size expression would not affect the result of the operator, it is unspecified whether or not
> the size expression is evaluated.

Can someone please provide an example illustrating the text above?

Comment: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP44-C.+Do+not+rely+on+side+effects+in+operands+to+sizeof%2C+_Alignof%2C+or+_Generic

Comment: `sizeof(int[foo()])`: the value of the size expression *would* affect the result of the operator; `foo` is called. `sizeof(int(*)[foo()])`: the value of the size expression *would not* affect the result of the operator; it is unspecified whether `foo` is called.

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct that for `size_t s = sizeof(int(*)[foo()]);` at file scope it is still unspecified whether `foo` is called? If "the constant expressions shall not contain function-call", then why it is not (if so) specified that `foo` is not called in this case? GCC/Clang produce no diagnostics, while ICC produces `error: function call is not allowed in a constant expression`.